# Verify a solution to a heat problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Verify that the following are solutions of the heat equation $u_{t}=ku_{xx}$

$u_{1}=e^{-k\pi^2t}sin(x\pi)$

$u_{2}=e^{-9k\pi^2t}sin(3x\pi)$

$u_{3}=e^{-9k\pi^2t}cos(3x\pi)$

I don't understand too much about heat problems so my first thought is to solve for $u_{1t}$ and $u_{1xx}$ and plug them into the original equation and solve and see if I get a true statement.

I got $u_{1t}=(-k\pi^2e^{-k\pi^2t})(sinx\pi)+(\pi cosx\pi)$ and
$u_{1xx}=(-\pi^2 sinx\pi)(e^{-k\pi^2t})$

After plugging them in and simplifying I get $e^{-\pi^2t}(sinx\pi)(-k^2\pi)=-cosx\pi$ and now I'm stuck. I don't know if I am using the right method, if there is a formula or concept I am neglecting or if there is an error somewhere.

Comment: Can you explain why should $u_{1t}$ have addendum $\pi \cos x\pi$ ?

Comment: Ahh I see I misused the product rule for derivatives. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: That is basically all you have to do. If $u$ satisfy the heat equation then $u_t(x,t) - k u_{xx}(x,t) = 0$ for all $(x,t)$. Thus the right method here is the one you have started on; compute $u_t - k u_{xx}$ for $u_1,u_2,u_3$ and check if it evaluates to $0$. Note that if you just can find a single value of $(x,t)$ such that $u_t(x,t) - k u_{xx}(x,t)\not\equiv 0$ then $u$ is not a solution.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I got 0=0 after correcting some calculation errors.